# Sublime Text 2 config files on Windows

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-8, editor, sublimetext2

I found there are several config files for SL2 on Windows, one in:

```
 %AppData%\Sublime Text 2
```

and another one in

```
%SublimeText2InstallPath%\Data
```

So, which config files is used on Windows? and what is the purpose of having multiple copies of them? I find starting SL2 from the right-click context menu, running the .exe directly, and starting it from command line results in different configuration file being used, not sure what caused it. how do I set it so that it only uses just a single set of configuration files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [the Sublime Text Unofficial documentation page](https://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/basic_concepts.html?highlight=config).

EDIT:
Since I see this is/was a link only answer, here's the relevant text from that webpage:

> Sublime Text will look for resources inside the *packages* [emphasis mine] folder. We’ll
>   talk at length about packages later, but the short version is that, to
>   keep things tidy, Sublime Text has a notion of a package, that is, a
>   folder (or zip archive) that contains resources that belong together
>   (maybe they help compose emails faster, write HTML efficiently,
>   enhance the coding experience for C, Ruby, Go…).